# Pipe cmd.exe from a server application over a socket to a client application

Tags: java, sockets, process, cmd, pipe

I've got 2 applications - a server and a client. Basically what I wanna do is to control the cmd.exe on the server machine remotely from my client application - just piping the client input to cmd.exe and the output of cmd.exe to the client application.

At the start I receive:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
```

So everything seems to be okay, but I can't send a command from the client app to the cmd.exe. The server app receives the cmd, e.g. "help" but the command doesn't arrive at the cmd.exe and I don't know why. I hope someone is able to help me with that problem.

**Server Code**

```
package net.api.windows.command.shell;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class CommandShellServer implements Runnable {

// - Init - //
private Socket socket;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private InputStream IN;
private OutputStream OUT;
private ObjectInputStream ObjIN;
private ObjectOutputStream ObjOUT;

// ___________________________________ //

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CommandShellServer();
}

public CommandShellServer() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Starting server..");
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(65000);
        System.out.println("Server started!");
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("\n" + "Client connected!");

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe").redirectInput(Redirect.PIPE)
                .redirectOutput(Redirect.PIPE).redirectError(Redirect.PIPE);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        final BufferedReader ProcessIN = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        final BufferedReader ProcessERROR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
        final BufferedWriter ProcessOUT = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));

        // Socket OutputStream
        Thread P_OUT = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while(true) {
                        String x = "";
                        if((x = ProcessIN.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println("Process says: " + x);
                            OUT = socket.getOutputStream();
                            ObjOUT = new ObjectOutputStream(OUT);

                            ObjOUT.writeObject(x);
                            ObjOUT.flush();
                        }
                    }
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
                }
            }
        });
        P_OUT.start();

        // Socket Error OutputStream
        Thread P_ERROR = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while(true) {
                        String x = "";
                        if((x = ProcessERROR.readLine()) != null) {
                            OUT = socket.getOutputStream();
                            ObjOUT = new ObjectOutputStream(OUT);

                            ObjOUT.writeObject(x);
                            ObjOUT.flush();
                        }
                    }
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
                }
            }
        });
        P_ERROR.start();

        // Socket InputStream
        Thread P_IN = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while(true) {
                        IN = socket.getInputStream();
                        ObjIN = new ObjectInputStream(IN);

                        String x = "";
                        if((x = ObjIN.readObject().toString()) != null) {
                            System.out.println("Client says: " + x);
                            ProcessOUT.write(x);
                            ProcessOUT.flush();
                        }
                    }
                } catch(IOException e1) {
                    System.out.println(e1.getMessage().toString());
                } catch(ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                    System.out.println(e2.getMessage().toString());
                }
            }
        });
        P_IN.start();

    } catch(IOException e1) {
        System.out.println(e1.getMessage().toString());
    }
}
}
```

---

**Client Code**

```
package net.api.windows.command.shell;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

public class CommandShellClient {

// - Init - //
private static Socket socket;
private static InputStream IN;
private static OutputStream OUT;
private static ObjectInputStream ObjIN;
private static ObjectOutputStream ObjOUT;

// ___________________________________ //

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Connceting to server..");
        SocketAddress sockAddr = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.21", 65000);
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(sockAddr, 5000);

        if(socket.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Connected!" + "\n");

            // Socket InputStream
            Thread Thread_IN = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while(true) {
                            IN = socket.getInputStream();
                            ObjIN = new ObjectInputStream(IN);

                            String x = "";
                            if((x = ObjIN.readObject().toString()) != null) {
                                System.out.println("Process says: " + x);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch(IOException e1) {
                        System.out.println(e1.getMessage().toString());
                    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                        System.out.println(e2.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                }
            });
            Thread_IN.start();

            // Socket OutputStream
            Thread Thread_OUT = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        BufferedReader SYSTEM_IN = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                        while(true) {
                            String x = "";
                            if((x = SYSTEM_IN.readLine()) != null) {
                                OUT = socket.getOutputStream();
                                ObjOUT = new ObjectOutputStream(OUT);

                                ObjOUT.writeObject(x);
                                ObjOUT.flush();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch(IOException e1) {
                        System.out.println(e1.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                }
            });
            Thread_OUT.start();
        }
    } catch(IOException e1) {
        System.out.println(e1.getMessage().toString());
    }
}
}
```

---

**SOLUTION**

At the server code, in the last Thread (P_IN), you have to type:

```
ProcessOUT.write(x);
ProcessOUT.newLine();
ProcessOUT.flush();
```

..instead of:

```
ProcessOUT.write(x);
ProcessOUT.flush();
```

The ProcessOUT.newLine() is **important**!

Comment: I hope someone can answer this!  When you get it running be sure to run the server as administrator and post the ip address.

Comment: Can you append `\r\n` at the end of the `ProcessOUT.print(x)`, since the cmd process wants a linebreak before executing a command.

Comment: Man thats so crazy.. xD I have found the solution -> editing my first post.